# (Unity) Is it possible to animate an object from a color back to it's original using an Animator?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

The behavior I'm trying to get out of Unity's Animator looks like this in code:

```
Color animationColor = Color.red;
Color originalColor = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.GetColor("_Color");
//...
renderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.Lerp(animationColor, originalColor, timeElapsed/animationTime));
```

I have no problem getting the animator to Lerp between two set colors, but I would like to have destination color be the original color of the object. Can this be done with the Animation system?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible just with the Animation System itself but you could just have a script attached which assigns a property named `OriginalColor` and have a function to return to this color when ever you want.

Such script could look like:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ChangeColor : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public Renderer Renderer;
    public Color OriginalColor;
    private bool _isOriginal
    public bool DoLerp = false;
    
    void Start() {
        Renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>()
        OriginalColor = Renderer .material.GetColor("_Color");
    }
    
    void Update() {
        if(!DoLerp)
            return;
        // timeElepsed stuff
        if(!isOriginal) {
            renderer.material.SetColor(
                "_Color", 
                Color.Lerp(
                    animationColor,
                    originalColor, 
                    timeElapsed/animationTime
                )
            );
        } else {
            renderer.material.SetColor(
                "_Color", 
                Color.Lerp(
                    originalColor, 
                    animationColor,
                    timeElapsed/animationTime
                )
            );
        }
        // If timeElepsed = end time then set DoLerp to false
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that this works, I have it working as a script myself. I was just wondering if it was possible to get this behavior from the animator.

Comment: There may be some hack but I thin kthat this will be the much cleaner solution. But you may keep your question opened (by not marking my answer as correct) so maybe someone else can tell you better than me :D